# How to WRITE a structure?

Tags: data-structures, abap

How can I do the following:

```
data: ls_header type BAPIMEPOHEADER.
" fill it
write ls_header.
```

currently I'm getting an error because `write` can not parse the complex type to a string. Is there a simple way to get this code running in abap?

Comment: Do you need to use `WRITE` or are other means to display the contents acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
DATA: g_struct TYPE bapimepoheader.

DO.
  ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-index OF STRUCTURE g_struct TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<f>).
  IF sy-subrc NE 0.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.
  WRITE: / <f>.
ENDDO.
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not exactly the answer you expect: If you list each field.

This can be done quite easy via the Pattern-mask in SE38:

1. Select the Write-pattern:
   [image]
2. Enter the structure you want:
   [image]
3. Select the fields
   [image]
   Confirm with "Copy"

Confirm and you get

```
WRITE: bapimepoheader-po_number,
       bapimepoheader-comp_code,
       bapimepoheader-doc_type,
       bapimepoheader-delete_ind,
       bapimepoheader-status,
       bapimepoheader-creat_date,
       bapimepoheader-created_by,
       bapimepoheader-item_intvl,
       bapimepoheader-vendor,
       bapimepoheader-langu,
       bapimepoheader-langu_iso,
       bapimepoheader-pmnttrms,
       bapimepoheader-dscnt1_to,
       bapimepoheader-dscnt2_to,
       bapimepoheader-dscnt3_to,
       bapimepoheader-dsct_pct1,
       bapimepoheader-dsct_pct2,
       bapimepoheader-purch_org,
       bapimepoheader-pur_group,
       bapimepoheader-currency,
       bapimepoheader-currency_iso,
       bapimepoheader-exch_rate,
       bapimepoheader-ex_rate_fx,
       bapimepoheader-doc_date,
       bapimepoheader-vper_start,
       bapimepoheader-vper_end,
       bapimepoheader-warranty,
       bapimepoheader-quotation,
       bapimepoheader-quot_date,
       bapimepoheader-ref_1,
       bapimepoheader-sales_pers,
       bapimepoheader-telephone,
       bapimepoheader-suppl_vend,
       bapimepoheader-customer,
       bapimepoheader-agreement,
       bapimepoheader-gr_message,
       bapimepoheader-suppl_plnt,
       bapimepoheader-incoterms1,
       bapimepoheader-incoterms2,
       bapimepoheader-collect_no,
       bapimepoheader-diff_inv,
       bapimepoheader-our_ref,
       bapimepoheader-logsystem,
       bapimepoheader-subitemint,
       bapimepoheader-po_rel_ind,
       bapimepoheader-rel_status,
       bapimepoheader-vat_cntry,
       bapimepoheader-vat_cntry_iso,
       bapimepoheader-reason_cancel,
       bapimepoheader-reason_code,
       bapimepoheader-retention_type,
       bapimepoheader-retention_percentage,
       bapimepoheader-downpay_type,
       bapimepoheader-downpay_amount,
       bapimepoheader-downpay_percent,
       bapimepoheader-downpay_duedate,
       bapimepoheader-memory,
       bapimepoheader-memorytype,
       bapimepoheader-shiptype,
       bapimepoheader-handoverloc,
       bapimepoheader-shipcond,
       bapimepoheader-incotermsv,
       bapimepoheader-incoterms2l,
       bapimepoheader-incoterms3l.
```

Now you can make a simple replacement of `bapimepoheader` with `ls_header` and you have an output of all fields of the structure.

Maybe this is not elegant and you must adapt your report, if the structure changes. But I like this way, because often I don't need all fields and I can select the fields in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways, one is procedural, the other is oop.
Here is the procedural approach.

1. Select  the structure's fields (or whatever else You might need ) from  the data-dictionary table DD03L into a local internal table.
2. Loop over the table into a work-area
3. Check, whether current field is a flat single datatype, and if so,
4. Assign component workarea-fieldname of structure ls_header into anyfieldsymbol
5. Write anyfieldsymbol

Do You need the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Class **CL_ABAP_CONTAINER_UTILITIES** was specially introduced for that by SAP.

Use `FILL_CONTAINER_C` method for output the structure in a `WRITE` manner:

```
DATA: ls_header type BAPIMEPOHEADER.

CALL METHOD CL_ABAP_CONTAINER_UTILITIES=>FILL_CONTAINER_C
 EXPORTING
  IM_VALUE                = ls_header
 IMPORTING
  EX_CONTAINER            = DATA(container)
 EXCEPTIONS
  ILLEGAL_PARAMETER_TYPE = 1
  others                 = 2.

WRITE container.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write your structure to a string and then output the string. Same method idoc segments are created.